# What is this animation style? I would call it "serious", but maybe gritty?

Tags: terminology

Often times in anime, I see a serious section accentuated by a gritty, more serious, more old school, animation type.  There will be many frames of animation, and the animation will be very fluid.  Usually this is done within a light-hearted anime, presumably for contrast with the main part of the show.  The example I have is not the best one, but gives you an idea of what I'm talking about.

The opening scene of [Golden Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Boy_%28manga%29#OVA) has a super serious vibe to it, and then goes into the regular style for the anime.  This is a screenshot of the scent in the opening I am referring to:

[image]

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47Hg0QIo1x8) has the opening, and the first 3 seconds are the most "serious style" of the opening.  Note that not in all cases are these clips of animation visually dark like this (for example having a black background.)  I think this art style is more often present when depicting fantasy anime, but I'm not sure.

Is there a name for this style of animation?  Ultimately, I would like to look for anime that use this style of animation throughout, so I am looking for something I can use to search The Internets for (aka a search term).

If I can think of another example, I will edit this question to add it.

Comment: I don't know if that style has a name, but try looking for action shows from the 80s and early 90s. That's where you'll mostly find it.